# Preserve drive letters when installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drive-letter

If you start installing Windows 7 on drive D: from within Windows XP, you see correct drive letters after installation, i.e. XP on C: and 7 on D:. However, if you boot from a DVD and install it, you find the volume on which Windows 7 is installed is called C: regardless of the partition order.

One time, I started the installation from DVD but corrected all drive letters by `DISKPART`, then immediately installed Windows (without restart) hoping that it will name the drives as new sort, but I failed. The setup ignored my drive assignments and again Windows partition was called C:!

Is there a way to instruct Windows setup to use drive letters other than its defaults similar to what is achieved when it is run from within XP?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to put Windows on a volume other than C:? Are you trying to accomplish some sort of dual boot configuration?

Comment: Indeed, I usually install several versions of OSs on my computer for several purposes: compatibility, research, learning, defrag,... However, the main thing annoying me, even with single OS, is that drive letters are not in order of their location! When I look at a letter, I need to immediately recognize where it locates on the hard drive. Microsoft decided to set the windows drive always C because they believe that most users don't understand OS drive is not necessarily C and this causes difficulties helping and supporting entry level users.